# XML Schema: "use='required'" with default value

Tags: xml, schema, parsing

In an XML Schema, is it possible to have an element which has `use='required'` **and** a default value (e.g. `<xs:attribute name="Version" type="U8" use="required" default="02"/>`)?

Comment: oXygen 16, which uses Xerces, says, "The property default is present in the attribute, so the value of use must be optional."

Answer (score 10):

At least XMLSpy chokes on this one:

> [...] In attribute declaration 'Version', 'use' must have the value 'optional' because the attribute 'default' is present.

A look into [*XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) yields *3.2.3 Constraints on XML Representations of Attribute Declarations*:

> [...] If `default` and `use` are both present, `use` must have the ·actual value· `optional`. [...]

So the answer obviously is: **NO**